# svg circle not registering mouseover very well

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 map with zoom functionality that has circles representing various cities. For some reason when I mouseover the circles (mouseover shows a tooltip, and clicking shows some lines), it is very difficult to get it to register. It seems to only register near the border of the circle and not the entire shape, but I haven't found a discernable pattern yet. Here is my relevant code:

CSS:

```
circle {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke: "green";
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", 3)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return line_color([Math.floor(d.diversity * num_lines)])
    })
    .style("stroke", "#000000")
    .style("stroke-width", "0.05px")
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on("click", fade(0))
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

[Here it is in action, to demonstrate the problem](http://andrewjudson.github.io/music-viz/)

Comment: Why do you have such a small stroke-width?

Comment: Aethestics. Why, do you think it could be affecting it?

Comment: That's the only thing I see that's out of the ordinary but I Otherwise, it's likely something else is getting in the way.

Comment: That's the only thing I see that's out of the ordinary. I assume you're scaling, otherwise that's not even being rendered. Likely, though, it's some other element getting in the way, which will be hard to figure out without a link to a larger example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @BenLyall in that having the links being drawn after the circles is what is causing the problem. In SVG, the depth is controlled by the order on which elements are drawn. A simpler solution, though, is to make the links ignore pointer events. Try adding `.style("pointer-events", "none")` to the links. I did that using developer tools in the link you provided and the tooltips are shown as soon as you move over a circle.

Answer (score 2):

Your links are being drawn after your nodes, which means that they are "on top" of the nodes.  Your pointer events aren't making it to the circles, as the links are masking it.

In your code you've got

```
    var data = d3.json("data/city_data.json", function(error, data) {
    var num_lines = data.links.length;
    var line_color = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, num_lines]).range(["#99CCFF", "#000066"]); //scale color by sqrt to seperate it out
    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr("r", 3)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return line_color([Math.floor(d.diversity * num_lines)])
        })
        .style("stroke", "#000000")
        .style("stroke-width", "0.05px")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on("click", fade(0))
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    var link = g.selectAll(".link")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return line_color([Math.floor(d.nlp_1 * num_lines)]);
        })
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            source_node = data.nodes[d.source];
            return projection([-1 * source_node.lon, -1 * source_node.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            source_node = data.nodes[d.source];
            return projection([-1 * source_node.lon, -1 * source_node.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            target_node = data.nodes[d.target];
            return projection([-1 * target_node.lon, -1 * target_node.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            target_node = data.nodes[d.target];
            return projection([-1 * target_node.lon, -1 * target_node.lat])[1];
        });
```

Try doing:

```
var data = d3.json("data/city_data.json", function(error, data) {
    var num_lines = data.links.length;
    var line_color = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, num_lines]).range(["#99CCFF", "#000066"]); //scale color by sqrt to seperate it out

    var link = g.selectAll(".link")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return line_color([Math.floor(d.nlp_1 * num_lines)]);
        })
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            source_node = data.nodes[d.source];
            return projection([-1 * source_node.lon, -1 * source_node.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            source_node = data.nodes[d.source];
            return projection([-1 * source_node.lon, -1 * source_node.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            target_node = data.nodes[d.target];
            return projection([-1 * target_node.lon, -1 * target_node.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            target_node = data.nodes[d.target];
            return projection([-1 * target_node.lon, -1 * target_node.lat])[1];
        });

    var node = g.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([-1 * d.lon, -1 * d.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr("r", 3)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return line_color([Math.floor(d.diversity * num_lines)])
        })
        .style("stroke", "#000000")
        .style("stroke-width", "0.05px")
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on("click", fade(0))
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

The items you draw last in your SVG will be on top.  This has the advantage of tidying up the visualisation so the endpoints of the links are under the node, making it look a little neater.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.style("pointer-events", "all")` to the circles. The [default](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) is only to have mouseover on what's visible but you want anything in the interior whether rendered or not.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/8dvko7qf/) showing it working

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding that to the CSS and as .style, but it didn't seem to help. This really seems like it would be the solution so I don't know why it isn't working

Comment: This may help a bit, but the actual problem is as per my answer.